# Why won't oracle sql developer recognise my if statement

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement

I am using oracle SQL developer and am trying to run a query with an if statement in it.

I have defined a variable and assigned a value to it.

```
define
var buyer varchar2(1)

/* define variable values */ 
exec :buyer := 'Yep'

if :buyer = 'Yep' then 
begin
dbms_output.put_line('Yep');
else 
dbms_output.put_line('Nope');
end;
```

However, when I run the script, I get an error message stating that IF is an unknown command.

Error starting at line : 8 in command -
if :buyer = 'Yep' then
Error report -
Unknown Command

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Because you can't use `if` outside of a PL/SQL block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a DECLARE-BEGIN-END block to run IF-ELSIF-ELSE-END conditions.
Based on your sample code, I'm assuming this is what you would like to do.

```
DECLARE
  buyer VARCHAR2(3) := 'Yep';
BEGIN
  IF ( buyer = 'Yep' ) THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Yep' );
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('Nope');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

You could run this as a script in sql developer. HTH!

Answer (score 1):

Look up the PLSQL Syntax:

```
DECLARE
  variable type;
BEGIN
  IF variable = 'test'
  THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('J');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('N');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for the help both. That's cleared that up... :)